# Test Flight iOS app built using XCode 7.3 not working iPhone version 10

Tags: ios, xcode

I pushed an app in `TestFlight` which was built using **XCode 7.3.1**.
When we install the app in iPhone with `version 10.0`, the app gets installed but crashes in the very first screen.

But the same app from `TestFlight` is working fine in iPhone having `version 9.0.2`.

Has anyone faced this issue? Can some one please tell me how can this be resolved?

Thanks

Comment: Try to collect crash report

Comment: We are not getting the crash reports.

Comment: Make sure to build your app in Release Mode not in Debug. The app may only crash when in Release. @bably

Comment: Try connecting the device to Xcode and view the device logs while the app runs and crashes. That might give you a hint. It is a good idea to use a library like Crashlytics for reporting crashes

Comment: @KAR I don't think we can upload Debug builds on testflight any longer. It requires builds be created using a Distribution cert now - with either Adhoc or Store provisioning

Comment: Version 9.0.2 is a rather old version. You should upgrade to make sure it works on the latest 9-version.

Comment: many syntax's were changed ! and iOS 10 doesn't support older code? May that effected?

Comment: pre iOS 10 camera access request could cause runtime exception (needed additional info.plist item)